# How to change a row in a single <tr>

Tags: php, html, html-table

This Program is printing each data in a new row. I want it to print 3 data in a single row and then change row and print the other 3 data's in a new row. I have tried to use for loop but it was not giving me required output. Kindly tell how to do this in this program

```
    <table width="550" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" bordercolor="#000000">  
      <tr>        
        <th  align= "left"><a href="#"><table width="160" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

<?php   
    /*Inner Page- Products exists in Certain Category!!
    ======================================================*/

   $sub2_query = "select * from sub_categories where category_id=$category_id ";
   $sub2_query_run = mysql_query($sub2_query);
   while ($sub2_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($sub2_query_run))
   {                
       $sub2_category_id = $sub2_query_fetch['sub_category_id'];

       $inner_query = "select * from products inner join product_description 
              on products.product_id= product_description.product_id
            where sub_category_id= $sub2_category_id";
       if($inner_query_run = mysql_query ($inner_query))
       {                
           while($inner_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($inner_query_run))
    {       
           $product_id = $inner_query_fetch['product_id'];
           $inner_image_query = "select * from product_images 
                              where product_id=$product_id";

           $inner_image_query_run = mysql_query($inner_image_query);
           //PRINTING imagesss      
           echo "</th><tr><td align='center'>"; 
               echo "<div id='border'>";
           echo  "<td>";
           echo "<a href='index_product_details2.php?product_id=$product_id' >";    
           $inner_image_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($inner_image_query_run);
           echo "<img src=http://localhost/cms/". 
            $inner_image_query_fetch['images']." height='150' width='150' alt=\"\" />
            </td>
            </tr>
        </div>";

?>

      <tr>
        <td align="center">

    <?php       
    //PRINTING NAMES
print_r($inner_query_fetch['name']);
    echo "<br> Price: ";
    print_r($inner_query_fetch['actual_price']);
    echo "</a>";
    echo "<br><br>";                                
       }
    }else{
        echo mysql_error();
      }
    }
}
?>
</td>
</tr>      
    </table>
```

Comment: You should use PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements instead of mysql_ functions, they've been deprecated.

Comment: As above and I'd start again to be honest. running queries in the middle of outputting your table looks horrible. Get the data first, then run through  the returned data displaying it

Comment: stackoverflow needs one thing not accept any code with mysql_ functions! how many times it has been stated not to use mysql_ functions still they are being used!

Answer (score 0):

try this its just example iam giving

```
<tr><?php  $i=0;
while($inner_query_fetch=       mysql_fetch_array($inner_query_run))
            {   

            if($i%3=="0"){  echo "</tr><tr>"; }?>

    <td> your html</td><?php $i++;}?></tr>
```

Comment: Should this be starting with <tr>, can't see a close for the <td>

Comment: Also would need an increment on $i and a reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some pseudo code so you can find the logic:

```
$columns = 3;
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   if($counter%$columns == 0) echo "<tr>";

   echo "<td>the things you want to output</td>";

   if($counter%$columns == 0) echo "</tr>";
   $counter++;
}
```

---

The module(% symbol) means if the rest obtained dividing two numbers, 10/3 = 3 (+ 1) the 1 would be the module in this case, so you only print the tr's when the row is a multiple of 3. it's a pretty common practice, used also to do alternate row colors for example (using $rowNumber%2);

**NOTES!!**:

You shouldn't use mysql_ functions anymore, they are deprecated, and unsafe (for sql Injections),
You should have a look at mysqli functions or PDO, personally I recommend learning PDO, as the queries are parametrized and it's very safe, and I like the logic and readability you get with it. Links:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

http://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php